# Cast a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, casting, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I want to know, how can I cast a: `JScrollPane` inside a `JTextArea`.

Basically, is a text area, with a: scroll pane, inside of this.

Here I put some of my code:

```
JTextArea txtarea = new JTextArea(); 
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txtarea, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

JTabbedPane tabbed = new JTabbedPane();
tabbed.addTab("Text", null, scroll, "Text");     


savebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent A){
txtarea = (JtextArea) tabbed.getSelecetedComponent();
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showSaveDialog(null);}});
```

With the last code, I create the: text area, and added a: scroll pane.
All is fine here, but I made a JTabbedPane, where I add the text area, but how I put the scroll pane, I need to put the: scroll pane, in the tab...

How I said, all is fine here, but in the console I get a exception which says,

```
JScrollPane cannot be cast to javax.swing.JTextArea...
```

Can you help me, or give an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code and provide a [mcve]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code that you have posted. Can you point out to the exact line which throws the `ClassCastException`? I was able to perfectly render the text area in a tabbed pane with your code without any Exceptions.

Comment: Also, you have to understand that there is no concept of *Casting* one Object to another in Java. Only the reference can be casted. So if you are seeing this ClassCastException, it means that there is an illegal cast coded somewhere in your code. But clearly, that piece of code is not posted in your question.

Comment: @anacron do you mind if I bookmark this to use your explanation in the future? It's so simple and yet so good. (Not that those contradict, they go along rather well)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, I forgot post the other part of my code... So, later of that, I create a "Save" button, to save the text of the JTextArea, so, now, I updated the code with this part.

Comment: In fact, If I delete the: JScrollPane from my: JTextArea, I can save the file with non problems, and all works perfectly, but If, I add the: JScrollPane, appears the exception.

Comment: @ItamarGreen, please go ahead!

Comment: @SthatycSoul. are you trying to save the data in the `txtArea` to the file in the `Save` button? If so, you don't need to use `tabbed.getSelectedComponent` to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
txtarea = (JTextArea) ((JScrollPane)tabbed.getSelectedComponent()).getViewport().getView();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tryed with something "Similar", puting, scroll = (JScrollPane) tabbed.getSelectedComponent(); But creating the viewport as a variable, ViewPort v = new ViewPort(scroll); But nothing worked, appearing more exceptions... Anyway, thank you, with your code works. 
I did not know you could cast up 2 times in line. But well, thank your for your time, I really appreciate. regards :)

Comment: @SthatycSoul. `I did not know you could cast up 2 times in line` - well maybe you can, but it is much easier to write the code as single statements on separate lines. It makes it much easier to debug code especially when you use a debugger. You get points for writing maintainable code, not putting all the code on a single line.  So write the code in two statement, 1) get the scrollpane from the tab, 2) get the text area from the viewport. Also, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark  so people know the problem has been solved.